iTerm2 - run a command in every new pane
I'm using iTerm2 and oh-my-zsh.
Whenever I start a session — a new iTerm2 window — it reads my .zshrc file and runs a few commands — e.g. getting the right Node version from .nvmrc. But when I open a new pane (or tab) I need those commands to re-run.
I'm not saying I need the whole .zshrc to be reapplied.
How can I setup a script to run in every new session/tab/pane?
